# Recursively making/parsing children in Java

Tags: java, parsing, recursion

I'm trying to parse a tree of nodes recursively, but every child I add evaluates to the last value.

Example: parsing 2+3 should make a node that evaluates 2 and a node that evaluates 3, but instead I get 2 nodes that evaluate to 3.

According to the debugger, subBefore is "2" and subAfter is "3" as it should be.

Constructing a new Operation adds the arguments as children. Why do I end up with children that evaluate to the same value?

Code is below. Term is pretty much the same thing but checks for * and / instead of + and -

```
Full code:

public class Operation extends ASTNode {

static char op; 

  private Operation(ASTNode... n) { super(n); }



  public static Operation parse(String s) {

      String str = s.trim();

    if(Term.parse(str) != null) return new Operation(Term.parse(str));
    else {

// now make substrings

    int lastOpPlus = str.lastIndexOf('+');
    int lastOpMinus = str.lastIndexOf('-');

    if (lastOpPlus > lastOpMinus) {
        op = '+';

        String subAfter = str.substring(lastOpPlus+1);
        String subBefore = str.substring(0, lastOpPlus);

        if(Operation.parse(subBefore)!=null && Term.parse(subAfter) != null) {
            return new Operation(Operation.parse(subBefore), Term.parse(subAfter));
        }

    }

    return null;
    }
  }

  public double eval(java.util.Map<String,Double> symtab) {
    // first check if state is okay checkState();

      if(arity() > 1) { 
          return (getChild(0).eval(symtab)+getChild(1).eval(symtab));
      }
      //System.out.println(arity());
      //getChild(1).eval(symtab);
      else{ 
          return getChild(0).eval(symtab);
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do Operation.parse() and Term.parse() have side-effects of any kind? I.e. do they modify any global variables?  BTW, when asking questions on SO it's better to provide the code where the problem might be occurring.  Then we don't have to guess.

Comment: they set a single character to be + or -, which is used in the evaluating method

Comment: Without seeing the source code there's no way for anybody to do better than guess.  If you want help, post the source for Operation and Term.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code. Term is the same thing. I'm basically working on a really simple calculator program that takes a string in and evaluates it by recursively breaking the string down into parts.

Comment: yes...is that not allowed? I'm trying to receive as little help as I can, I just want to get past this block that's stopping me from continuing with the assignment.

Comment: Homework is allowed, and you've followed the guidelines by posting code and asking a specific question.  Your code problems are probably deeper than a simple question, however.  You may want to discuss this with your prof or TA to get more specific guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing the code for `Operation.parse`, `Term.parse`, and the `Operation` constructor, but my guess is that you are sharing a buffer or variable somewhere.

On a separate note, you're doing the parse work twice. It might be good to reorganize your code like this:

```
Object before = Operation.parse(subBefore); // a more specific type, not Object
Object after = Term.parse(subAfter);
if (before != null && after != null) {
    return new Operation(before, after);
}
```

Comment: turns out it was the static variable. I didnt know/think different children would still share the static variables, but share they did. That resulted in the last number being parsed to be shared by all children. Thanks for the help!